# Finding right quotient of $a^*b^*/b^*.$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages

I argue that right quotient of  $a^*b^*/b^*$ is $a^*$,is that true?any help or argument  to accept or reject my argument will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^*b^* / b^* = \{ w \ | \ \exists \ x, \ x \in b^* \land wx \in a^*b^*\} = a^*b^*$. This is because $wx \in a^*b^* \text{ AND } x \in b^*$ means $w$ is of the form $a^ib^j$ for some $i,j \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. Finish it off now.